# add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module` NOT WORKING

Tags: reactjs

I m trying to make this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@toast-ui/react-image-editor) run on my ReactJs project, but importing it in one of my component with this line:

```
import ImageEditor from '@toast-ui/react-image-editor';
```

returns this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module
> '@toast-ui/react-image-editor'.
> 'c:/Users.nextjsgenerator/node_modules/@toast-ui/react-image-editor/dist/toastui-react-image-editor.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/toast-ui__react-image-editor` if it exists or add a new
> declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@toast-ui/react-image-editor';`

So I have tried the suggestions given:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/toast-ui__react-image-editor
```

returns an error:

```
Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2 Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
```

then I tried the second option:

1. I created an empty *tsconfig.json* file in the root of the project, then ran `npm run dev` again
2. then I updated the *tsconfig.json* with

   "compilerOptions": {
   "typeRoots": [
   "./typings",
   "./node_modules/@types/"
   ],
   ....

But I still get the same error message:

[image]

Also created a *typings/index.d.ts* file with this content:

```
declare module '@toast-ui/react-image-editor';
```